# jquery on click not working on hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slider

[jquery problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv3Ym.png)
I have a carousel slider: 4 elements are visible and 6 are not (simple slide). My problem is this:

Jquery SlideElement.on("click") does not work when elements that are not visible appear. How can I run this?

```
$(function () {
 const sepeteekle = $('.product-card__addtocart');
  sepeteekle.on('click', function() {
   alert("working working!");
  });
});
```

You can watch the video: https://streamable.com/e3mx6

Comment: The elements are probably dynamically removed/recreated try `$(document).on('click', '.product-card__addtocart', function() {...`

Comment: so how can i get $(this)? its getting document now.

Comment: No it doesn't. `this` will still refer to the `.product-card__addtocart` element that triggered the event

Comment: No problem, glad it helped